# ES6 imports and node_modules hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

i am learning react and writing my own components but i ran into an issue with project organisation.

here is my tree

```
 Project_Folder
  - Components
    - Form
      - index.js
      - form.less
      - package.json
    - Button
      - index.js
      - button.less
      - package.json
  - node_modules
    - <million unknown packages>
  - application.js
  - webpack.conf.js
```

In my `application.js` i import form like that: `import Form from './Components/form/index.js';` Recently i figured if i just put my components folder in to `node_modules` folder i can import my components with `import Form from 'Components/Form';` which is much better. but then developing this components becomes a hell just because whenever i go in to node folder it has millions of other modules which are required by webpack or babel or mini-CSS-extractor.

is there any solution to a better organization within node_modules, or maybe i should install dev tools globally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not a good idea** to have your components inside the node_modules folder. **Unless** you are creating **shareable** code between teams through other tools/frameworks. Using your components there create a whole bunch of a problems that you have not faced YET :( !

i.e Node modules give the flexibility to share code using only the `package.json` and ignoring them with `.gitignore`. And reinstalling them through `npm install`.

Can you see the problem here?

To be able to *share your components* now inside the node_modules the options are:

- either push your files without the folder losing your components (**Not an option after all** :()
- send the whole application and the modules which could be **huge** and forces everyone to have to download a massive repo or even in case of upload to the repository (git, bitbucket, gitlab) (**taking forever to upload**)
- create a whole module for that component only to write './X' into 'X' (**requires extra effort and does not sound a good deal for me**)

Structuring folder is a delicate topic. It envolves a little bit of analysis of what suits your taste better and there is no right way of doing (even if you find *experts* that claim that such way is the correct)

For a better approach you could check the react documentation:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure

  and a tutorial that I think will suffice in your case
- https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-structure-a-react-app-or-why-theres-no-such-thing-3ede534ef1ed

Goodluck:)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely you shouldn't keep your components in node_modules catalog, that's where you keep only dependencies of your app. Here's might be a good [read for you](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/). Especially when you'll be using git repository, you shouldn't copy your `node_modules` catalog in there, because, as you've noticed - it's huuge. Let any other person working on this code to install dependecies on it's own, after cloning a repo.

There's few conventions - one will be to keep your components in `src/` catalog. My advise for you will be to install globally `create-react-app` (a boilerplate generator for React sites, [available here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) and check it's conventions. Should be a great lesson for you.

One thing that concerns me is why there's `package.json` inside each component? There should be only one `package.json` file for a whole project. [Read here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file).

If you want your file paths shorter and easier to read/use, you can create aliases with Webpack [like this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid messing with your node_modules folder. It is best to let npm or yarn write into it.

1. What will happen if you need to delete your node_modules and rebuild it? All your code will be lost.
2. What will happen if you want to share your code or push it to remote repository.
   You will be force to share your nodes_modules folder around.
3. As for react project best file structure, [checkout this article on react website.](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html)
   There is not really a best structure, all depend on you and your team. Usually people:

**Group files by feature**

```
common/
  Avatar.js
  Avatar.css
  APIUtils.js
  APIUtils.test.js
feed/
  index.js
  Feed.js
  Feed.css
  FeedStory.js
  FeedStory.test.js
  FeedAPI.js
profile/
  index.js
  Profile.js
  ProfileHeader.js
  ProfileHeader.css
  ProfileAPI.js
```

**Group files by type**

```
api/
  APIUtils.js
  APIUtils.test.js
  ProfileAPI.js
  UserAPI.js
components/
  Avatar.js
  Avatar.css
  Feed.js
  Feed.css
  FeedStory.js
  FeedStory.test.js
  Profile.js
  ProfileHeader.js
  ProfileHeader.css
```